# How to recursively call a single fetch request in a chain of fetch requsts

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, recursion, fetch

I am making a node.js and express web app that uses the node-fetch module. Below is a snippet of the key parts of my code

```
fetchGeoLocation(geoApiKey)
.then(coordinates => {
   data x = getSomeData(); //returns data needed for next fetch API call.

   return fetchWithRetry(//various parameters provided by var data...);

}
.then(powerData =>{
   ///continue on...

}
```

For some context: fetchWithRetry receives area as a parameter and outputs electrical power. It is recursive because the power output must be below a certain threshold. If it is below such threshold, the value is returned, else the fetchWithRetry() is called again with changed inputted parameters.

This are the important parts of my fetchWithRetry() function:

```
function fetchWithRetry(params...){
   return fetch(///powerData)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(powerData => {

    if( //powerData isn't good){
       fetchWithRetry(change params...)
    }
    return powerData;
```

**TL;DR-->**
**The following is the exact problem:**

The last callback, powerData, does not wait for the result of fetchWithRetry and it's potential following recursive calls. I have verified that fetchWithRetry works correctly, but the recursive calls are made AFTER the last .then() call is made, therefore it is not waiting for it.

I have tried using async/await for coordinates and fetchWithRetry but the last .then() continues to not wait for the recursive call to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only forgot to `return` the recursive `fetchWithRetry`. Here is one example:

```
const timeOutPromise = (i)=>{
  return new Promise((res)=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(i)
    }, 100);
  })
}

function fetchWithRetry(i){
  return timeOutPromise(i)
  .then(d=>{
    process.stdout.write(d+" ");
    if(d<10){
      return fetchWithRetry(d+1)
    }else{
      return d
    }
  })
}

fetchWithRetry(0).then((d)=>{
  console.log("\nThe Latest Value: ",d);
  console.log("done");
})
```

the result is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
The Latest Value:  10
done
```